# Multiple PPPoe connection to multiple computers via 1 modem?

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have a TP-link Wireless Router TP-WR542G and a Zyxel Prestige 650m-61 modem.
I have 2 separate PPPoe accounts from my ISP.

I'm thinking of using those 2 accounts simultaneously using my 1 modem.
I wanted to have 1 account to be connected to the wireless router and 1 account to my computer. Is that possible? How?

TQ

Comment: You will need 2 modems that are connected to server. Then your computer connects to the server. Thr purpose of the server is to decide which internet to use. You cannot use both at the same time, and you cannot use 1 to send info and the other to receive for the same request. But you could say-1 connection for games, and another for internet, youtube, downalods, torrents. But the server is the key point.. QoS router.. not really what you asking about.. but its the principle

Comment: @ppumkin: 1) Two modems are not required if you only have a single line. 2) What do you mean by "server"? 3) The "server" does *not* decide which route to use, the router does. 4) There is only one Internet, "decide which internet" is nonsense. 5) You *can* use two Internet connections at the same time (although not two PPPoE connections). 6) You *can* use one connection to send and another to receive.

Comment: @grawity So what you sayin is that ONE modem on one telco line can log into 2 PPPoe accounts at the same time and double his bandwidth?

Answer (score -1):

You would need 2 DSL modems and 2 DSL lines to do what you want.

Why not simply let your router share one line with the 2 computers?

Alternatively, you could also request that a dry-loop be installed and use that loop for the second connection.

Comment: I wanted to this so that i don't have to share bandwidth with other computers. If these is really not possible, how about solutions to limit other computers' speed remotely?

I have looked up on the internet and some said about bridging the modem to get multiple session simultaneously. Is that possible for my case? Since i don't want to spend money on another modem.

Dry loop is not available in my country either ( Malaysia ).

Thx a lot anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking for [Quality of service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) (QoS) :

> Quality of service is the ability to
>   provide different priority to
>   different applications, users, or data
>   flows, or to guarantee a certain level
>   of performance to a data flow.

Unfortunately, your router does not support QoS.